# Gaps between overbars and square roots in exported graphics in some fonts

Tags: export, latex, fonts

I make my slides in LaTeX and my pictures in Mathematica. I want to keep the fonts the same throughout, so when I have an image with text in it, I convert the text to "CMU Bright" font in Mathematica before I export the image as a pdf.

If my image includes an overbar or a square root, it looks like this:

```
Image = Graphics[Text[Style[{OverBar[x] Sqrt[x],"Overscript[x, _],Sqrt[x]"}, FontFamily->"CMU Bright"], {1, 3}]]
```

[image]

But when I export it as a pdf there are big gaps between the x and the bar.

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "image.pdf", Image ]
```

[image]

Does anyone know what's causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you see in v.11. After exporting to PDF and opening in Adobe Acrobat, [this is what I see](http://imgur.com/a/dAjEV), i.e. no extraneous spacing. Notice also that you have extra `"` in your code which I think are not intended. You also should not use `Image` since it's a built-in symbol.

Comment: Don't use `Image =...`.  `Image` is a builtin symbol.  `Export[..., Image]` is also invalid.  It should be `Export[..., "PDF"]`.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen this very problem before.  Typesetting does sometimes change when exporting to PDF, and the result may change slightly from version to version.

I recommend that you simply use LaTeX to typeset these, through the [MaTeX package](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX).

This problem *was the actual reason* why I wrote [MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX).  Coincidentally, I was annoyed by precisely a square root and an overbar, just like you ...

```
<<MaTeX`

MaTeX[OverBar[x] Sqrt[x]]
```

[image]

```
MaTeX["\\bar x \\sqrt{x}"]
```

[image]